# Count sum of value for each element in coma separated column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe such as :

```
VALUE Names 
1     Sp1,Sp2
1     Sp2
2     Sp3,Sp4
4     Sp2,Sp1
```

And I would like to count for each `df$Names` in coma separated way, the sum of `df$VALUE` and get a new dataframe such as :

```
Name Sum
Sp1   5
Sp2   6
Sp3   2
Sp4   2
```

Here is the dataframe in dput format if it can helps:

```
structure(list(VALUE = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 4L), Names = c("Sp1,Sp2", 
"Sp2", "Sp3,Sp4", "Sp2,Sp1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `separate_rows` to split the 'Names' column, and then do a group by `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  separate_rows(Names) %>%
  group_by(Names) %>% 
  summarise(Sum = sum(VALUE))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  Names   Sum
  <chr> <int>
1 Sp1       5
2 Sp2       6
3 Sp3       2
4 Sp4       2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution.

```
s <- strsplit(as.character(df1$Names), ",")
s <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(s), \(i) {
  data.frame(Sum = rep(df1$VALUE[i], length(s[[i]])), Names = s[[i]])
}))
aggregate(Sum ~ Names, s, sum)
#  Names Sum
#1   Sp1   5
#2   Sp2   6
#3   Sp3   2
#4   Sp4   2
```

Answer (score 2):

This does the trick.

```
library(tidyverse)

 x = structure(list(VALUE = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 4L), Names = c("Sp1,Sp2", 
                                                "Sp2", "Sp3,Sp4", "Sp2,Sp1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                   -4L))

y = mutate(x, 
       var1 = str_split(Names,  "\\,", simplify = T)[,1],
       var2 = str_split(Names,  "\\,", simplify = T)[,2]) %>%
pivot_longer(c(var1,var2), names_to = "var", values_to = "Name") %>%
 select(-var, Names) %>%
 filter(Name  != "") %>%
group_by(Name) %>%
summarise(Sum = sum(VALUE))
```